# Retrieving the selected item in a paper-element dropdown

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I have the following code following the examples at https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples/blob/master/web/paper_dropdown.html and https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples/blob/master/web/paper_dropdown.dart

**EDITED**

**.html**

```
<paper-dropdown-menu 
  label='Click to select..' 
  on-core-select='{{onCoreSelectCountryHandler}}'>
  <paper-dropdown class='dropdown'>
    <core-menu id='country' class='menu'>
      <template repeat='{{country in countries}}'>
        <paper-item>{{country.name}}</paper-item>
      </template>
    </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

**.dart**

```
final List<Country> countries = [
  const Country('Afghanistan', 'AF'),
  const Country('Åland Islands', 'AX')];

class Country {
  final String name;
  final String code;
  const Country(this.name, this.code);
}

void onCoreSelectCountryHandler(dom.CustomEvent e, var detail) {
    var detail = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(e)['detail'];

  if (detail['isSelected']) {
  // DOES NOT WORK - HOW DO I GET THE SELECTION ATTEMPTED BELOW
  // The detail should be related to the Country class but 
   // I can't seem to relate it so I could get the selection.
  var kuntry = (detail['item'] as PaperItem).text;

}
```

How do I retrieve the selected element in the dropdown (that displays normally) using dart code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

I think this is the easiest way

```dart
void onCoreSelectCountryHandler(dom.CustomEvent e, var detail) {
  print(countries[$['country'].selected].name);
  // or if you really need to access the `<paper-item>` element
  print(detail['item'].text);
}
```

**old**

There is no `selected` in `paper-dropdown`. Wrap a `core-menu` within the `paper-dropdown` which provides `selected`.

see
- https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-menu.html and the example at https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-dropdown-menu.html

Comment: No problem, it's just to keep the Dart area well maintained :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple make the country list observable

```
final List<Country> cuntries = toObservable[
  const Country('Afghanistan', 'AF'),
  const Country('Åland Islands', 'AX')}]
```

The selection is retrieved.

My oversight.

Comment: That was all the change I had to make with my code for it to work. Your answer print(detail['item'].text); confirms this. If I remove the toObservable it will still not print the item. After all, I asked the question because my code was not working.

Comment: I see. I can't imagine how this is related. Maybe you use it differently in your application. When you load the countries from the server for example or modify the content of the list in any other way after the application was loaded, then you definitely need `toObservable`